# C# - How can programm a textbox that add tags into a listbox just like stackoverflow tags are coded?

Tags: c#, windows, listbox

Everytime I click enter, he deletes the textbox, adds the text of the word into the listbox?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the code-behind of an Windows Forms App that does what you asked in a **REALLY BASIC** way, would be the following:

```
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 namespace WindowsFormsApp1 {
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
     {
         if(e.KeyChar == 13) //checks if "enter" was pressed
         {
             listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);//adds the text to the list
             textBox1.Clear(); //clear the text of the textbox
         }
     }
 } }
```